# Can I install Ubuntu/Debian in USB and use it in both PC and Mac?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows, mac

I am very new to this Linux or even Dual Boot systems. I currently I own two systems: PC with Windows 10 (AMD Ryzen 3700X CPU with Nvidia RTX GPU), and second is my Macbook Pro (Intel 4870Q with Nvidia 750M).

Can I install Ubuntu on a USB hard disk and then switch between both as a dual boot system? So I can use that USB on PC when I am working on my PC and then when I want to work on Laptop I use that USB on my laptop.

I know it is highly unlikely due to different CPU, GPU and drivers in both systems. But I need a second opinion on this.

Very Thanks.

Comment: You need to partition in advance & make sure you have an ESP - efi system partition on USB drive. All systems boot external drives in UEFI mode from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. But Ubuntu's Ubiquity will install to internal drive's ESP. You can either copy ESP to external drive's ESP or reinstall grub on external. There is a work around on install. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same. Both computers will be using the `amd64` architecture.

I just tested with a Debian install image, it boots perfectly. Go ahead and test it with a live Ubuntu/Debian, that will also let you see how compatible the rest of the hardware is.

When you start the Mac, you can keep Alt pressed until the EFI boot selection appears and then choose the disk. I have [rEfit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/), but I don't think you need it.

Then, after boot, the X server will pick up the right driver (if it is supported), the kernel the right modules, etc.

There might some more work to do, like making sure that the network interfaces in both computers work, etc. Or the resolution on both screens is good. But there should be no problem booting the same drive from both.